# Firebase Realtime shows download usage almost 10x than the actual download

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm listening to a single node like this:

```
final reference =  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
                       .child(kUsersNode);

StreamSubscription<Event> subscription = reference.onValue.listen((_){});

subscription.onData(_handleOnDone);
```

This means that the listener only gets called at the first time it is listening and whenever there is a data update.

The node has data structure like this:

```
- users
  |- uid
      |- h: 0
      |- l: 0
      |- p: 0
      |- c: 0
      |- m: 0
```

Now I have 3 records (3 UIDs) and the total is only 204 Bytes written in the usage tab. I estimated 1 data fetch should be around 68-90 Bytes

Now please look at the usage graph below:

[image]

There was no access at all the whole day to the database (since I'm the only one doing this). Then I tested to do one fetch plus one time opening the console. So probably the usage meter should show around 360 Bytes, but in the usage meter it shows 3.4KB !!! How's that happen?
Moreover, after that I just did 1 change on one number, which the app gets it through the listener plus one more time opening the console, then there is another 15KB download recorded!! That is insane!!

Can someone help to explain to me? And how to avoid this?

Now I'm considering to change my database to another one.

Comment: Isn't it true that when you're listening to this value and you only get an update when changed, that in the background it's actually polling the value on an interval?
Or maybe not getting the actual data, but at least _some kind of_ response indicating whether there's new data yet.

Comment: On my app I only get the data once. I think it does not fire if there is no new data.

Comment: I mean, in the background it's checking data but only passing it onto your functionif it has changed.
Maybe you could use a network analyzer (Wireshark for example) to see how much data is actually sent/received from your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL encryption overhead:

There is a cost associated with the SSL encryption overhead necessary for secure connections. On average, this cost is approximately **3.5KB for the initial handshake**, (see that in your graph) and approximately tens of bytes for TLS record headers on each outgoing message.

Additionally, Firebase console data adds a bit: Although this isn't usually a significant portion of Realtime Database costs, Firebase charges for data that you read and write from the Firebase console.